# Cubos coloridos por fora mas não por dentro

Tags: javascript, three.js

Fiz um cubo, pintei os lados (esquerda, direita, cima e baixo) e coloquei uma borda, ficou bem semelhante, porém, como não tem a parte de frente e a de trás é possível ver o que tem atrás da borda

Parece que, olhando de fora, está pinado como o esperado, porém, olhando do lado de dentro está transparente

Como resolver esse problema? Se tiver uma forma melhor de fazer essas bordas das janelas também ta valendo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
// Cena
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
scene.rotation.y = 0.5;

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
camera.position.z = 7;
camera.position.x = 2;
camera.position.y = 10;

// Renderizador
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Criar janelas
function edificeWindow(config) {
    // Estrutura
    const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    // Aparência
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: config.color}); //, transparent: true, opacity: 0

    // Janela
    let window = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
    window.position.x = config.x;
    window.position.y = config.y;
    window.position.z = config.z/4;

    // Material das bordas
    const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, linewidth: 2 });
    
    // Cria a borda
    const wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(window.geometry), lineMaterial);
    wireframe.renderOrder = 1;
    window.add(wireframe);

    return window;
}

// Criar bordas
function edificeBorder(config) {
    // Estrutura
    const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(config.w, config.h, 1);

    // Aparência
    const material = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0 }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0 }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0 }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0 }),
    ];

    // Mesh
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
    mesh.position.x = config.x;
    mesh.position.y = config.y;
    mesh.position.z = 0.25;

    // Material das bordas
    const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, linewidth: 2 });

    // Cria a borda
    const wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(mesh.geometry), lineMaterial);
    wireframe.renderOrder = 1;
    mesh.add(wireframe);

    return mesh;
}

// Prédio
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(8, 12, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x85b9dd});
let edifice = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
edifice.position.x = 2;
edifice.position.y = 10;
edifice.position.z = -0.1;
scene.add(edifice);

// Inicialização da animação
(function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();

/* Descrição
    w = width
    h = height
    x = posição x
    y = posição y
    z = posição z
    color: cor de fundo
        |- 0xc2fce2 = azul
        |- 0xceffbb = verde
        |- 0xe4ffc6 = amarelo
        |- 0xeedfd1 = vermelho
*/

// Lista de janelas
const windows = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 15,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 15,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 15,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 15,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 14,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 14,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 14,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 14,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 13,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 13,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 13,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 13,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 12,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 12,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 12,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 12,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 11,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 11,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 11,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 11,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 10,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 10,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 10,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 10,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 9,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 9,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 9,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 9,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 8,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 8,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 8,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 8,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 7,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 7,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 7,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 7,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 6,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 6,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 6,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 6,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 5,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 5,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 5,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 5,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}];

const border = [{
    w: 1,
    h: 2,
    x: 0,
    y: 14.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 15
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 15
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 15
}, {
    w: 2,
    h: 1,
    x: 1.5,
    y: 14
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 2,
    x: 3,
    y: 13.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 13
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 13
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 13
}, {
    w: 2,
    h: 2,
    x: 0.5,
    y: 11.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 12
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 12
}, {
    w: 2,
    h: 1,
    x: 2.5,
    y: 11
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 10
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 10
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 2,
    x: 2,
    y: 9.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 10
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 9
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 9
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 3,
    x: 3,
    y: 8
}, {
    w: 3,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 8
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 7
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 7
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 7
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 2,
    x: 0,
    y: 5.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 6
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 6
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 6
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 5
}];

// Adiciona as janelas na cena
for(const config of windows) {
    scene.add(edificeWindow(config));
}
// Adiciona as bordas na cena
for(const config of border) {
    scene.add(edificeBorder(config));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

**Observação:** a janela tem duas bordas, as linhas que separam um cubo do outro, e outra que separa 1 ou mais cubos um do outro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe uma propriedade no objeto passado no `MeshBasicMaterial` chamada `side`, definindo-a com o valor `THREE.DoubleSide` o objeto criado terá a estilização nos dois lados:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, side: THREE.DoubleSide })
```

```js
// Cena
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
scene.rotation.y = 0.5;

// Camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 1000);
camera.position.z = 7;
camera.position.x = 2;
camera.position.y = 10;

// Renderizador
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Criar janelas
function edificeWindow(config) {
    // Estrutura
    const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    // Aparência
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: config.color}); //, transparent: true, opacity: 0

    // Janela
    let window = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
    window.position.x = config.x;
    window.position.y = config.y;
    window.position.z = config.z/4;

    // Material das bordas
    const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, linewidth: 2 });
    
    // Cria a borda
    const wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(window.geometry), lineMaterial);
    wireframe.renderOrder = 1;
    window.add(wireframe);

    return window;
}

// Criar bordas
function edificeBorder(config) {
    // Estrutura
    const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(config.w, config.h, 1);

    // Aparência
    const material = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
    ];

    // Mesh
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
    mesh.position.x = config.x;
    mesh.position.y = config.y;
    mesh.position.z = 0.25;

    // Material das bordas
    const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x92c1b0, linewidth: 2 });

    // Cria a borda
    const wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(new THREE.EdgesGeometry(mesh.geometry), lineMaterial);
    wireframe.renderOrder = 1;
    mesh.add(wireframe);

    return mesh;
}

// Prédio
const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(8, 12, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x85b9dd});
let edifice = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, material);
edifice.position.x = 2;
edifice.position.y = 10;
edifice.position.z = -0.1;
scene.add(edifice);

// Inicialização da animação
(function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();

/* Descrição
    w = width
    h = height
    x = posição x
    y = posição y
    z = posição z
    color: cor de fundo
        |- 0xc2fce2 = azul
        |- 0xceffbb = verde
        |- 0xe4ffc6 = amarelo
        |- 0xeedfd1 = vermelho
*/

// Lista de janelas
const windows = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 15,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 15,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 15,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 15,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 14,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 14,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 14,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 14,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 13,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 13,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 13,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 13,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 12,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 12,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 12,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 12,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 11,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 11,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 11,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 11,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 10,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 10,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 10,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 10,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 9,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 9,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 9,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 9,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 8,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 8,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 8,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 8,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 7,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 7,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 7,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 7,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 6,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 6,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 6,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 6,
    z: 1,
    color: 0xeedfd1
}, {
    x: 0,
    y: 5,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xe4ffc6
}, {
    x: 1,
    y: 5,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xc2fce2
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 5,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}, {
    x: 3,
    y: 5,
    z: 0,
    color: 0xceffbb
}];

const border = [{
    w: 1,
    h: 2,
    x: 0,
    y: 14.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 15
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 15
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 15
}, {
    w: 2,
    h: 1,
    x: 1.5,
    y: 14
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 2,
    x: 3,
    y: 13.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 13
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 13
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 13
}, {
    w: 2,
    h: 2,
    x: 0.5,
    y: 11.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 12
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 12
}, {
    w: 2,
    h: 1,
    x: 2.5,
    y: 11
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 10
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 10
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 2,
    x: 2,
    y: 9.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 10
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 9
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 9
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 3,
    x: 3,
    y: 8
}, {
    w: 3,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 8
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 0,
    y: 7
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 7
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 7
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 2,
    x: 0,
    y: 5.5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 6
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 6
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 6
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 1,
    y: 5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 2,
    y: 5
}, {
    w: 1,
    h: 1,
    x: 3,
    y: 5
}];

// Adiciona as janelas na cena
for(const config of windows) {
    scene.add(edificeWindow(config));
}
// Adiciona as bordas na cena
for(const config of border) {
    scene.add(edificeBorder(config));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```